# SQL query with lots of JOIN conditions is very slow

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I've inherited a SQL Server 2008 R2 project that, amongst other things, does a table update from another table:

- `Table1` (with around 150,000 rows) has 3 phone number fields (`Tel1`,`Tel2`,`Tel3`)
- `Table2` (with around 20,000 rows) has 3 phone number fields (`Phone1`,`Phone2`,`Phone3`)

.. and when any of those numbers match, `Table1` should be updated.

The current code looks like:

```
UPDATE t1
SET surname = t2.surname, Address1=t2.Address1, DOB=t2.DOB, Tel1=t2.Phone1, Tel2=t2.Phone2, Tel3=t2.Phone3,
FROM Table1 t1 
inner join Table2 t2
on
(t1.Tel1 = t2.Phone1 and t1.Tel1 is not null) or
(t1.Tel1 = t2.Phone2 and t1.Tel1 is not null) or
(t1.Tel1 = t2.Phone3 and t1.Tel1 is not null) or
(t1.Tel2 = t2.Phone1 and t1.Tel2 is not null) or
(t1.Tel2 = t2.Phone2 and t1.Tel2 is not null) or
(t1.Tel2 = t2.Phone3 and t1.Tel2 is not null) or
(t1.Tel3 = t2.Phone1 and t1.Tel3 is not null) or
(t1.Tel3 = t2.Phone2 and t1.Tel3 is not null) or
(t1.Tel3 = t2.Phone3 and t1.Tel3 is not null);
```

However, this query is taking over 30 minutes to run.

The execution plan suggests that the main bottleneck is a `Nested Loop` around the Clustered Index Scan on `Table1`. Both tables have clustered indexes on their `ID` column.

As my DBA skills are very limited, can anyone suggests the best way to improve the performance of this query? Would adding an index for `Tel1`,`Tel2` and `Tel3` to each column be the best move, or can the query be changed to improve performance?

Comment: Apply non clustered index on Tel1,Tel2,Tel3 of both the tables

Comment: If a field is null then an `=` won't return true - you don't need all those `and t1.Tel1 is not null`. Also, you're updating the fields that you're querying on, which could create some data loss (if `Tel1 = Phone2` but `Phone1` is null). Try normalising the phone numbers first (i.e. have a linked table to hold the phone numbers)

Comment: Can you add some test data please (say in SQLFiddle)

Comment: All sorted; @Vishwajeet, the index has made a difference after splitting the query up as per the answer below. @Keith, thank you - of course, I knew that `NULL`s wouldn't be evaluated, they were just there for effect :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On first look, I would recommend eliminating all your OR Conditions from the select.

See if this is faster (*it's converting your update into 3 distinct updates*):

```
UPDATE t1
SET surname = t2.surname, Address1=t2.Address1, DOB=t2.DOB, Tel1=t2.Phone1, Tel2=t2.Phone2, Tel3=t2.Phone3,
FROM Table1 t1 
inner join Table2 t2
on
(t1.Tel1 is not null AND t1.Tel1 IN (t2.Phone1, t2.Phone2, t2.Phone3);

UPDATE t1
SET surname = t2.surname, Address1=t2.Address1, DOB=t2.DOB, Tel1=t2.Phone1, Tel2=t2.Phone2, Tel3=t2.Phone3,
FROM Table1 t1 
inner join Table2 t2
on
(t1.Tel2 is not null AND t1.Tel2 IN (t2.Phone1, t2.Phone2, t2.Phone3);

UPDATE t1
SET surname = t2.surname, Address1=t2.Address1, DOB=t2.DOB, Tel1=t2.Phone1, Tel2=t2.Phone2, Tel3=t2.Phone3,
FROM Table1 t1 
inner join Table2 t2
on
(t1.Tel3 is not null AND t1.Tel3 IN (t2.Phone1, t2.Phone2, t2.Phone3);
```

Comment: I thought of this approach too. It will not produce exactly the same results, but may be close enough. Differs in the fact that any matches from the first query will be re-updated in the second and third queries, but having said that I don't understand how the OP query works, as each `t1` row can possibly match multiple `t2` rows

Comment: I don't see how the results will conflict.  The first query looks only at t1.Tel1 column, second query looks only at t1.Tel2, etc...

Comment: When `t1.Tel1` matches in the first query, `t1.Tel2` and `t1.Tel3` are also updated. `t1.Tel2` and `t1.Tel3` will then definitiely match in queries 2 and 3.

Comment: I guess t1.Tel1, t1.Tel2, t1.Tel3 could have the same, generating 3 updates (instead of one), but doesn't the OP query also works in much the same way?

Comment: @Paul ok, you're right. I didn't notice that t1.Tel2 and t1.Tel3 were being updated in the SET clause..

Comment: Thanks all - I've broken down the query into individual UPDATEs as per the above. Once I'd done that, SSMS's Execute Plan view suggested I added some indexes, which I've done (as also suggested by @Vishwajeet). Everything seems much faster now, thank you for your help! PS I realise the query is a bit rubbish, with the possibility of updating rows more than once - but apparently that's "by design" :/

Answer (score 1):

First normalise your table data:

```
insert into Table1Tel 
select primaryKey, Tel1 as 'tel' from Table1 where Tel1 is not null
union select primaryKey, Tel2 from Table1 where Tel2 is not null
union select primaryKey, Tel3 from Table1 where Tel3 is not null

insert into Table2Phone 
select primaryKey, Phone1 as 'phone' from Table2 where Phone1 is not null
union select primaryKey, Phone2 from Table2 where Phone2 is not null
union select primaryKey, Phone3 from Table2 where Phone3 is not null
```

These normalised tables are a much better way to store your phone numbers than as additional columns.

Then you can do something like this joining across the tables:

```
update t1
set surname = t2.surname, 
    Address1 = t2.Address1, 
    DOB = t2.DOB
from Table1 t1 
     inner join Table1Tel tel
         on t1.primaryKey = tel.primaryKey
     inner join Table2Phone phone
         on tel.tel = phone.phone
     inner join Table2 t2
         on phone.primaryKey = t2.primaryKey
```

Note that this doesn't fix the fundamental issue of dupes in your data - for instance if you have both Joe and Jane Bloggs in your data with the same phone number (even in different fields) you'll update both records to be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below query and let me know how long it will take to complete executing.

```
UPDATE t1
SET surname = t2.surname, Address1=t2.Address1, DOB=t2.DOB, Tel1=t2.Phone1, Tel2=t2.Phone2, Tel3=t2.Phone3,
FROM Table1 t1 
inner join Table2 t2
on (
    '|'+cast(t2.Phone1 as varchar(15)+'|'+cast(t2.Phone1 as varchar(15)+'|'+cast(t2.Phone1 as varchar(15)+'|' LIKE '%|'+cast(t1.Tel1 as varchar(15)+'|%'
    or '|'+cast(t2.Phone1 as varchar(15)+'|'+cast(t2.Phone1 as varchar(15)+'|'+cast(t2.Phone1 as varchar(15)+'|' LIKE '%|'+cast(t1.Tel2 as varchar(15)+'|%'
    or '|'+cast(t2.Phone1 as varchar(15)+'|'+cast(t2.Phone1 as varchar(15)+'|'+cast(t2.Phone1 as varchar(15)+'|' LIKE '%|'+cast(t1.Tel3 as varchar(15)+'|%'
    )
```

Replacing 3 OR with 1 LIKE should be faster. Just try it.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try something like the following which should hopefully avoid redundent updates.

```
UPDATE t1
SET surname = t2.surname,
    Address1=t2.Address1, DOB=t2.DOB, 
    Tel1=t2.Phone1, Tel2=t2.Phone2, Tel3=t2.Phone3
FROM
    Table1 T1
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT
    T1.ID AS T1_ID,
    T2.ID AS T2_ID
FROM
    t1.Tel1 = t2.Phone1

UNION

SELECT
    T1.ID AS T1_ID,
    T2.ID AS T2_ID
FROM
    t1.Tel1 = t2.Phone2

UNION

SELECT
    T1.ID AS T1_ID,
    T2.ID AS T2_ID
FROM
    t1.Tel1 = t2.Phone3

UNION

SELECT
    T1.ID AS T1_ID,
    T2.ID AS T2_ID
FROM
    t1.Tel2 = t2.Phone1

UNION

SELECT
    T1.ID AS T1_ID,
    T2.ID AS T2_ID
FROM
    t1.Tel2 = t2.Phone2

UNION

SELECT
    T1.ID AS T1_ID,
    T2.ID AS T2_ID
FROM
    t1.Tel2 = t2.Phone3

SELECT
    T1.ID AS T1_ID,
    T2.ID AS T2_ID
FROM
    t1.Tel3 = t2.Phone1

UNION

SELECT
    T1.ID AS T1_ID,
    T2.ID AS T2_ID
FROM
    t1.Tel3 = t2.Phone2

UNION

SELECT
    T1.ID AS T1_ID,
    T2.ID AS T2_ID
FROM
    t1.Tel3 = t2.Phone3

) X
ON T1.ID = X.T1_ID
INNER JOIN Table2 T2 ON X.T2_ID = T2.TD
```